# Поулчение имени класса

Tags: java

Подскажите как можно получить имя текущего класса и сделать нижний регистр(чтобы маленькими буквами был). Подзабыл вроде getClass().getName(), но что-то нето.

Comment: можно `getSimpleName` - без пакета будет

Comment: this.getSimpleName().toLowercase()?

Comment: @serey да, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

Функция getClass()

```
Integer a = 5;  
System.out.println(a.getClass().toString().toLowerCase());
```

Результат таков:

> class java.lang.Integer